# convert and reformat multiple month abbreviations into integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, strptime

Given the below column:

```
     col 
  0  NaN
  1  Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
  2  Jan,Jun,Jul
  3  Apr,May,Oct,Nov
  4  NaN
  ...
```

How to convert the months abbreviation to month number (int)? and replace tghe comma with a hyphen? The output should look like:

```
     col 
  0  NaN
  1  01-04-07-10
  2  01-06-07
  3  04-05-10-11
  4  NaN
  ...
```

Comment: What have you tried. Post [mre] and ask specific question. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with dictionary with months and if necesary is added `,` for replace to `-`:

```
d = {',':'-', 'Jan': '01', 'Feb': '02', 'Mar': '03', 'Apr': '04', 
              'May': '05', 'Jun': '06', 'Jul': '07', 'Aug': '08', 
              'Sep': '09', 'Oct': '10', 'Nov': '11', 'Dec': '12'}

df['col'] = df['col'].replace(d, regex=True)
print (df)

0          NaN
1  01-04-07-10
2     01-06-07
3  04-05-10-11
4          NaN
```